# I came across a tricky trouble about django Queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Tricky code:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=123)
user[0].last_name = 'foo'
user[0].save()  # Cannot be saved.
id(user[0])     # 32131
id(user[0])     # 44232 ( different )
```

user cannot be saved in this way.

Normal code:

```
user = User.objects.filter(id=123)
if user:
  user[0].last_name = 'foo'
  user[0].save()  # Saved successfully.
  id(user[0])     # 32131
  id(user[0])     # 32131 ( same )
```

So, what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In first variant your `user` queryset isn't evaluated yet. So every time you write `user[0]` ORM makes independent query to DB. In second variation queryset is evalutaed and acts like normal Python list.

And BTW if you want just one row, use `get`:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=123)
```

Comment: +1, more info about when a queryset is evaluated can be found in the doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated

Answer (score 2):

when you index into a queryset, django fetches the data (or looks in its cache) and creates a model instance for you. as you discovered with `id()`, each call creates a new instance. so while you can set the properties on these `qs[0].last_name = 'foo'`, the subsequent call to `qs[0].save()` creates a new instance (with the original last_name) and saves that

i'm guessing your particular issue has to do with when django caches query results. when you are just indexing into the qs, nothing gets cached, but your call `if users` causes the entire (original) qs to be evaluated, and thus cached. so in that case each call to `[0]` retrieves the same model instance

Answer (score 1):

Saving is possible, but everytime you access user[0], you actually get it from the database so it's unchanged. 
Indeed, when you slice a Queryset, Django issues a SELECT ... FROM ... OFFSET ... LIMIT ... query to your database.

A Queryset is not a list, so if you want to it to behave like a list, you need to evaluate it, to do so, call `list()` on it.

```
user = list(User.objects.filter(id=123))
```

In your second example, calling `if user` will actually evaluate the queryset (get it from the database into your python program), so you then work with your Queryset's internal cache.

Alternatively, you can use `u  = user[0]`, edit that and then save, which will work.

Finally, you should actually be calling `Queryset.get`, not `filter` here, since you're using the unique key.